# How to adjust print options through code?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have a ticket booking system in Joomla.

When user clicks on ticket link a ticket is shown on the site.

I am using a **barcode.php** file to generate the barcode image for ticket number.

Now there are 2 scenarios I used to print ticket.

1. When I print that ticket using `window.print()` or **Ctrl+P**, 2 pages get printed
   even though my ticket content is only single page.
2. When I use following javascript code to print specific part of the page, barcode image is not generated.

   ```
   function print_specific_div_content(){
       var content = "<html>";
       content += document.getElementById("divToPrint").innerHTML ;
       content += "</body>";
       content += "</html>";

       var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=552,height=477,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
       printWin.document.write(content);
       printWin.document.close();
       printWin.focus();
       printWin.print();
       printWin.close();
   }
   ```

My requirements are:

**Ticket should be printed only on single page**.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 :**

I modified my function as follow, but unfortunately it shows new window but no print dialog. :(

```
function print_specific_div_content(){
    var win = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=552,height=477,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    var handler = function() {
      win.print();
      win.close();
    };
    if(win.addEventListener)
        win.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
    else if(win.attachEvent)
        win.attachEvent('onload', handler, false);

    var content = "<html>";
    content += document.getElementById("divToPrint").innerHTML ;
    content += "</body>";
    content += "</html>";
    win.document.write(content);
    win.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When printing just the content, you need to wait for the document to load before printing so that the images will be loaded:

```
function print_specific_div_content(){
    var win = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=552,height=477,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');

    var content = "<html>";
    content += "<body onload=\"window.print(); window.close();\">";
    content += document.getElementById("divToPrint").innerHTML ;
    content += "</body>";
    content += "</html>";
    win.document.write(content);
    win.document.close();
}
```

Comment: I am calling that javascript function onclick event of a button. So image is aleady loaded. Isn't it?

Comment: No, because you just put "new" HTML into a new document in a new window, which needs to be parsed and have its images loaded.

Comment: Ohh right. But I am not getting how to use the code you have provided. Can you please explain?

Comment: You need to move the call to `print` and `close` into a handler for the `onload` event. You can use the code pretty much as I provided it, substituting in `content` and `printWin` and your own call to `window.open`.

Comment: Please check my **EDIT 1** What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps not all browsers fire the `onload` event properly in that fashion. Try the updated code in my answer.